# Aggregation count of mail domains using elastisearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have following documents in my index:

```
{
    "name":"rakesh"
    "age":"26"
    "email":"rakesh@gmail.com"
}

{
    "name":"sam"
    "age":"24"
    "email":"samjoe@elastic.com"
}

{
    "name":"joseph"
    "age":"26"
    "email":"joseph@gmail.com"
}

{
    "name":"genny"
    "age":"24"
    "email":"genny@hotmail.com"
}
```

Now i need to get the count of all mail domains. Like:

```
@gmail.com:2,
@hotmail.com:1,
@elastic.com:1
```

using elastic search aggregations.

I can able to find the records which matches the given query. But i need have a count of each domain.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be achieved by creating a sub-field that will contain only the email domain name. First create the index with the appropriate analyzer:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "email_domain_analyzer": {
            "type": "pattern",
            "pattern": "(.+)@",
            "lowercase": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "domain": {
              "type": "text",
              "fielddata": true,
              "analyzer": "email_domain_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then create your documents:

```
POST my_index/doc/_bulk
{ "index": {"_id": 1 }}
{ "name":"rakesh", "age":"26", "email":"rakesh@gmail.com" }
{ "index": {"_id": 2 }}
{ "name":"sam", "age":"24", "email":"samjoe@elastic.com" }
{ "index": {"_id": 3 }}
{ "name":"joseph", "age":"26", "email":"joseph@gmail.com" }
{ "index": {"_id": 4 }}
{ "name":"genny", "age":"24", "email":"genny@gmail.com" }
```

And finally, you can aggregate on the `email.domain` field and you'll get exactly what you need:

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "domains": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "email.domain"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I already had a huge data in my index . i didn't had analyzer for that index. can't we do any aggregations on the existing index. Sorry if i ask you a basic question. I am novice in es

Comment: What's the current mapping of your `email` field?

Comment: just a string i have given to that field."email": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }

Comment: You're out of luck then, you need to reindex your data with the analyzer I suggested

Comment: Thanks anyway for your quick help. I will try to reindex my data.

Comment: Sure, feel free if you have any other questions.